# Browserify + NodeJS [node: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado]

Tags: javascript, node.js

## Situação

Estou desenvolvendo uma extensão para Google Chrome, e preciso utilizar alguns módulos NodeJs então encontrei a ferramenta Browserify para que eu possa agregar módulos para utiliza-lo no navegador

## Ambiente

Possuo o NodeJs, NPM e o Browserify instalados na minha maquina ubuntu, modulo que desejo está em `node_module/uniq`

## Main.js

```
var unique = require('uniq');
var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];
console.log(unique(data));
```

## Comando

Dou o seguinte comando para escrever o código baseado em navegador

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

ele me retorna isso

## Erro

> /usr/bin/env: node: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Answer (score 12, accepted):

eu tive esse mesmo problema, instalei isso aqui e resolveu (:

sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

Não consegui resolver criando links simbólicos, não sei se meu exemplo se aplica a essa situação, mas talvez ajude.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911

Answer (score 3):

Digitando apenas o comando `env` é possível ver todas as variáveis utilizadas por ele. Procure por PATH, faça:

`env | grep -e '^PATH'`

Ele vai mostrar algo como:

`PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/android-studio/sdk/tools`

O node deve estar em um desses diretórios. Eu faço assim, coloco o node em
`/usr/local/lib`, depois crio um link simbólico em `/usr/local/bin`.

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/node/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node`

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

## Solução

O erro se encontrava no arquivo cms.js do modulo Browserify.

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js
```

Na alinha 1 encontramos o seguinte

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Notando que o `nodejs` está escrito sem o JS `node`, alterei ele para `nodejs`.
Alterando

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

Executei o seguinte comando novamente

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

E ele transformo as dependências do meu main.js em códigos que possam ser executados pelo navegador!

Encontrei a solução graças ao atilacamurca que posto ai em cima o problema de path. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui resolver isso, apena copiando o nodejs com o de nome node, isso eu fiz no Ubuntu 14.04, o correto era usar o mv para renomear o nodejs mas fiquei com medo de cagar alguma coisa ai copiei apenas.

Exemplo:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo cp nodejs node
```

Pronto apenas isso, depois disso tudo funcionou normalmente. Até agora ta tudo respondendo normal.

Answer (score 0):

## Esclarecimento

Não encontrei até o momento uma solução para esse problema, testei de varias maneiras e em outros SO. Devo estar fazendo algo errado no processo.

## Solução Alternativa

Foi utilizar essa ferramenta online, onde insiro o modulo que quero do nodejs e ele me retorno o código em um modo que o navegador consiga interpretar.

Link da ferramenta: http://wzrd.in/